# Could not parse the remainder: '[cat_id]' from 'menu[cat_id]'

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

I am new to django and jinja template.
I am getting below error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '[cat_id]' from 'menu[cat_id]'
```

I am trying to create dynamic tabs in my header for product categories, below is my code where error is happening:

```
{% for cat_id in menu %}
    <span class="navbar-item {% if 'sub_cat' in menu[cat_id] %} has-dropdown is-hoverable{% endif %}" style="{% if 'sub_cat' in menu[cat_id] %}align-items:center{% endif %}" >
```

`menu` is the dictionary and below is the sample structure for the same:

```
menu = {
1: {
    'category': 'Jewellery',
    'slug': 'abc',
    'sub_cat': {
        3: {
            'category': 'Earrings',
            'slug': 'def'
        }
    }
},
2: {
    'category': 'Apparel',
    'slug': 'ghi'
}
}
```

I am using python version 3.8, I tried degrading it to 3.7 as well, but error is still coming.

I am not sure if changing python version helps or not.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `menu.cat_id`

Comment: What is your view.py file?

Comment: @RezaHeydari how should i access "Jewellery" from above menu dictionary.

Comment: @AaronCloud this code is from my layout.html (base or common html file for header and footer). I have used context processors to send dictionary to parse categories dynamically in header. Does this has to do anything with my views.py, I am not sure about it.

`def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')`

Comment: @Aj06 No but it would be nice to see everything layed out. Its hard for me to try and connect all the dots without following the full trail.

Comment: @AaronCloud apologies, I have shared view for index in my previous comment. Should i share anything else which will help you to see the loopholes? Thanks in advance